# RPI File Browser for Touchscreen

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, raspbian-lite, web-interface

I'm building a Webinterface for the RPi with a 7" Touchscreen. I'm running Raspbian Lite with xorg and chromium-browser. If I now wanna upload a file to the webinterface (by a html input), then there appears a file-chooser which is absolutely not usable on touchscreen. Does anybody has an idea on how to solve this problem?